# select query to find max date in a row

Tags: java, mysql, sql, h2

want help in sql query, I am using H2 database

i have 12 dates (date with time) in a row, field name like Date_1, Date_2, Date_3... Date_12

like to know which has max date and Time. have to know whether is there any date which is less than 10 minutes from current time.

can some one help in sql query for the above

Answer (score 3):

You can use **[`GREATEST`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest)** to find max value from current row:

```
SELECT GREATEST(Date_1, Date_2, Date_3,... ,Date_12) AS Max_date_in_row
FROM your_table;
```

To find out:

> is there any date which is less than 10 minutes from current time

```
SELECT * 
FROM your_table
WHERE GREATEST(Date_1, Date_2, Date_3,... ,Date_12) > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -10 MINUTE);
```

Comment: Can you add 10 minutes difference in other direction too?

Comment: Max_date_in_row is the variable i should look in ResultSet, right? sorry i am new to sql ! I  dont know whether 'AS' is allowed in H2 database

Comment: @Skay `Max_date_in_row` is just alias for column. You can name it as you want for example `AS my_column`